# Using WebSpeech API through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webspeech-api

I have been trying to use the WebSpeech Api through angularjs. Everything seems to work but the model doesn't get updated at once.

If I start the recognition again, the model updates. Seems like some inner loop/other construct is holding angular to see the changes.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/ishankhare07/pen/BKaRNv?editors=1011) that I made.

Steps to reproduce:
 1. Click start, and speak
 2. After recognition detects end of speech hit start once again to start another recognition.
 3. As soon as the second recognition is started, the model is updated with previous transcript.

> Note: If a do console.log as below then it shows correct transcript, means the recognition part is working fine.

```
if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
  self.final = self.final.concat(event.results[i][0].transcript);
  console.log(event.results[i][0].transcript);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems perfect, except you forgot to call  $scope.$apply(); when you modified values to get it effect on view. So it should be like this,

```
angular.module('speech',[]);

angular.module('speech').controller('speechController', function($scope) {
  this.rec = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  this.interim = [];
  this.final = '';
  var self = this;

  this.rec.continuous = false;
  this.rec.lang = 'en-US';
  this.rec.interimResults = true;
  this.rec.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log('error!');
  };

  this.start = function() {
    self.rec.start();
  };

  this.rec.onresult = function(event) {
    for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
      if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
        self.final = self.final.concat(event.results[i][0].transcript);
        console.log(event.results[i][0].transcript);
        $scope.$apply();

      } else {
        self.interim.push(event.results[i][0].transcript);
      }
    }
  };

});
```

I have updated your [codepen](http://codepen.io/shankargurav/pen/NNWwRR?editors=1011) with working solution.

AngularJs creates a "watch" internally for the all data-bindings created in view and call $scope.$digest() which inturns iterate thorugh  all watches and checks if any of the watched variables have changed. When you call $scope.$apply() it internally calls $scope.$digest() so data-binding gets refreshed.

Listener directives, such as ng-click, register a listener with the DOM. When the DOM listener fires, the directive executes the associated expression and updates the view using the $apply() method.

When an external event (such as a user action, timer or XHR) is received, the associated expression must be applied to the scope through the $apply() method so that all listeners are updated correctly ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)).

So in your case view gets update when you click next start button again (ng-click)  and not when recording event occurs.

Also would be usefult to read [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

Comment: but i never needed to do anything like that before, isn't angular supposed to notice the changes for the model automatically? like it happens in most cases?

Comment: also this solution doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: check this [http://codepen.io/shankargurav/pen/NNWwRR?editors=1011](http://codepen.io/shankargurav/pen/NNWwRR?editors=1011), I can see values are being reflected in textbox. Do you any other problem with scripts?

Comment: yes this seems to work, but my question is still unanswered. Why do we need $scope.$apply? the model should see the change itself

Comment: that was really helpful. I still don't understand that doing an XHR using $http also returns a promise. But usually we never have to call $apply to update the model with the returned JSON?

Comment: If you read the angularjs scope documentation, there is already explaination for it "For mutations to be properly observed, you should make them only within the scope.$apply(). Angular APIs do this implicitly, so no extra $apply call is needed when doing synchronous work in controllers, or asynchronous work with $http, $timeout or $interval services."